# How to remove "css classes" when the "a href" is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a custom page template where i use WordPress posts to get images ( using feature images ) and I have made a gallery out of them.

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="pyete-vete">
            <a href="<?php echo the_field("peoplelink"); ?>" target="_blank">PYETE VETE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what i want to achieve is to remove .middle class when the HREF is empty.

Tried a lot of i found on stack overflow but none of them was successful till now.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to achieve the same? So that we can help in checking if you have missed something out.

Comment: Here <div  class="middle"> try putting below condition
`<div <?php if(!empty(the_field("peoplelink")){ ?> class="middle" <?php } ?>>`

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan tried but it didn't work ...

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt samples using jquery as other people suggested bellow on this question.

Comment: @xake and none of them worked?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt nope, maybe i'm doing something wrong but till now they didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the jQuery `each` function to loop through all `a` tags and check if `href` is empty.

```js
$('a').each(function(e){
    if($(this).attr('href')=='')
        $(this).closest('.middle').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <img class="img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="pyete-vete">
            <a href="" target="_blank">PYETE VETE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="middle">
        <div class="pyete-vete">
            <a href="sample.php" target="_blank">PYETE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running this snippet, it shows both "PYETE VETE" a href.

Comment: @xake in the first div middle  class is removed since it doesn't have a href

Comment: @xake i highlighted by a border if middle class is present

Comment: I used your code and changed it into addClass. So i added a new class and used CSS to remove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `the_field("peoplelink")` is empty:

```
<div class="<?php echo empty(the_field("peoplelink")) ? 'middle' : ''; ?>">
    <div class="pyete-vete">
        <a href="<?php echo the_field("peoplelink"); ?>" target="_blank">PYETE VETE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<div class="<?php if (the_field("peoplelink")){ echo 'middle'; } ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.middle').filter(function() {
  return $("a", this).attr("href") == "";
}).removeClass("middle");
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.middle').filter(function() {
  return $("a", this).attr("href") == ""
}).removeClass("middle")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <img class="img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="pyete-vete">
            <a href="" target="_blank">PYETE VETE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (untested):

```
if ($(".middle .pyete-vete a").attr('href') != '') { 
    $(".middle").removeClass("middle");
}
```